# Converting a xcodeproj from mac to iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I have a bare bones xcodeproj with just a main function and 1 target that links in the foundation framework. Is it possible to convert this into an iPhone xcodeproj? In other words is this enough or you need to set up other files such as .plist?

Answer (score 1):

Anyhow you should create new iPhone project, and add your source files into it. There is no possibility to automatically convert it.

Comment: This is very much the obvious option. I am sorry for not mentioning this, i just wanted to know if it's possible by say just changing a couple of project settings

Comment: You can convert from one to the other. The easiest way to find out exactly what you need to change would be to create a new project using an iPhone template. At that point you might as well just copy the functions over to the new project, though.

Comment: The truth is i am experimenting with CMake/GYP i can generate a mac based xcodeproj but somehow setting `SDKROOT: 'iphonesimulator4.1'` generates the iPhone based xcodeproj but i get an error `Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.`

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the Base SDK from Mac OS X to iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

If you did most code would not be recognised because `UIKit` is different to `AppKit` if you are quite fluent with both then think about copy paste all files import them into new iOS project you will get lots of errors depending on how big your project is, then you will go on and just replace the errors with the alternatives with the AppKit code. I have done this before and it is a long process.

There is probably a lot easier way to do this but that project was important for me so I just did it.